# How do I convert column names into Time Series names in R?

Tags: r, time-series

guys. I am a newbie in R, and I am trying to do something that seems very simple to me, though I can't find a good answer to solve it!

I am importing data from Excel (yeah, I know, but at work everything is in Excel).

```
x <- read.table(file = "clipboard", sep = "\t", header=TRUE)
```

My data is like this:

```
               CPI           CoreCPI
1              2.3             3.5
2              2.4             3.5
3              2.3             3.3
4              2.6             3.7
5              2.5             3.7
```

Then, I am trying to convert each column into a different time series:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(x) {
    CPI<-ts(x[,1],start=c(2014,11),end=c(2015,3),frequency=12)
    CoreCPI<-ts(x[,2],start=c(2014,11),end=c(2015,3),frequency=12)
}
```

But I have to rewrite all the names! Isn't there somehow R could preserve the colnames(x) vector as the names of each time series?

I tried

```
colnames(x)[,i]<-ts(x[,i],start=c(2014,11),end=c(2015,3),frequency=12)
```

But I get error messages:

```
Error in paste("serie", i, "sep= ") <- ts(x[, 1], start = c(2014, 11),  : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

Help!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Use `lapply` with `ts` like this:

```
L <- lapply(x, ts, start = c(2014, 11), frequency = 12)
```

giving a list of named time series:

```
> L
$CPI
     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2014                                         2.3 2.4
2015 2.3 2.6 2.5                                    

$CoreCPI
     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2014                                         3.5 3.5
2015 3.3 3.7 3.7
```

**2)** One can attach the list `L` as shown below but normally its preferable to use `L$CPI` and `L$CoreCPI` to refer to the series instead.

```
> attach(L) # creates objects CPI and CoreCPI
> CPI
     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2014                                         2.3 2.4
2015 2.3 2.6 2.5
```

**3)** Also note that one can create a multivariate time series simply like this:

```
 x_ts <- ts(x, start = c(2014, 11), frequency = 12)
```

giving:

```
 > x_ts
         CPI CoreCPI
Nov 2014 2.3     3.5
Dec 2014 2.4     3.5
Jan 2015 2.3     3.3
Feb 2015 2.6     3.7
Mar 2015 2.5     3.7

> x_ts[, "CPI"]
     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2014                                         2.3 2.4
2015 2.3 2.6 2.5
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly!